# Alternative to CSRF Protection for iFrame embed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, csrf-token

I am using a server side framework that implements a csrf token in a form for CSRF protection. In this app I am creating a form that needs to be implemented in an iFrame in other sites. Whenever I try to submit this form from the iFrame I get an error: `invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery)`.

Because of this I need to skip the CSRF protection for when the form is embedded. Are there alternatives I can use to protect my site in this scenario? Are there things I should do in this scenario because I can't use CSRF? Sorry I am new to web development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to make your form include the CSRF token as a hidden field? https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for check the `Form to external resources` section. If someone opens your form in an iframe and the form has the right csrf value in the hidden field I imagine it should work, not sure though

Comment: It does have that as a hidden field in the form and still receives that error.